# mongoose promise gives no response with findone()

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Here is the function that I use for create users, if the user exist, which means the findOne has result, then all the rest is fine, but when the user is not exist, which means the findOne can not get any result, then it get into no response, even the console.log is not printed. 
    function createUser(payload) {

```
return Users.findOne({'username': payload.username})
.then(result =>{
    console.log(result);
    if(result){
        res.render({message: 'Success registered.',
            statusCode: '200',
            result: result});
    }else{
        return {
            message: 'Success registered.',
            statusCode: '200'
        };
    }

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
}
```

This is the user schema :

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let timeZone = require('mongoose-timezone');

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
       type: String,
       required: true
},
password:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
phone:{
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
email:{
    type: String
},
role:{
    type:String,
    required: true
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
status:{
    type:String
}
});

userSchema.plugin(timeZone);
let profile = module.exports = mongoose.model('profiles', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code never makes it to the `catch` block if the user doesn't exist. If there is no result (e.g., the user doesn't exist), it goes through the `else` block and returns a 200 code with a message (apparently incorrectly) stating that the user has been created.

See [here in docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne): `findOne` returns `null` if query has no results.

Comment: The problem is when I am making the function call, it does not go into the .then function at all, not even the console.log(result), it gives no response in return